# Modernizr and fonts.com crashing IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-face, modernizr

I'm currently building a site where I'm using fonts.com to display a custom font for headers and subheaders. The font gets loaded via fonts.com javascript link and is then referenced in the CSS file as:

```
font-family: 'MyFontFromFontsDotCom';
```

It works fine and performs well. In IE8, however, the browser crashes after the font gets loaded (it never loads fully though) and the site. When I hit the "stop" button in the browser, the site gets rendered with the correct font.

I have a modernizr 2.6.2 running aswell which is referenced before the fonts.com javascript. When I remove the fonts.com javascript, the site runs just fine.

The fonts.com javascript reference is at the bottom of the body tag and the modernizr is at the head tag. I tried moving them around without any luck.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To say "the browser crashes" would mean that the browser process aborts completely.  Is that really what's happening?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a JSFiddle.net?

Comment: When the browser "crashes", it loads the site (without the font) and then just keeps loading. Can't interact with the site at all :) I'll try to see if I can get it working on jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh, and after a while I get the message "mysite.com is not responding due to a long-running script"

Comment: can you post the font.com javascript reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this issue when I was cross browser testing a site on IE 8. I fixed the issue by using the 'Non-javascript' (CSS) option.

You can get to this by going to the Manage Web Fonts section on fonts.com, selecting your project and then clicking the 'Publish Options' link.

In the window that pops up there is a tab for 'Option 2: Non-Javascript', this will give you a code snippet for CSS instead of Javascript. You should paste this in the head and then remove the Javascript snippet.

Comment: Spot on, Jordan! :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer was already accepted for this, and it is perfectly valid solution (using the CSS option instead of the Javascript option), but there is another possible solution if you do need the Javascript option (I like to have the -active classes added to my document).

It turns out there is a known issue with the fonts.com Javascript on IE8 when there are unclosed tags. So if you have a situation like:

```
<div><span>March 2014</div>
```

This will cause the fonts.com Javascript to cause troubles.

So find and fix unclosed tags with the W3C validator!